# React. Некорректная работа функции markTodoDone(todo) в приложении TodoList

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь изменить состояние конкретной тудушки в markTodoDone(todo) при нажатии о выполнении и изменении значения isChecked на true, а меняются все. Подскажите, что не так?

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.isEnterPressed = this.isEnterPressed.bind(this);
        this.markTodoDone = this.markTodoDone.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            text: '', 
            todoList: [
                {title:'Сделать тупую херню', isChecked: false}, 
                {title: 'Сделать тупую херню еще раз', isChecked: false}
            ]
        };
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    }

    isEnterPressed(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();

            this.setState({
                todoList: [...this.state.todoList, {title:this.state.text, isChecked: false}],
                text: ''
            });
        };
    }

    **markTodoDone(todo) {
        this.setState({
            todoList: this.state.todoList.map((todo) =>
                ({ title: todo.title, isChecked: (todo.isChecked === false) ? true : false}))
        })
        console.log(todo)
    }**
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <EntryField 
                    value={this.state.text}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                    onKeyDown={this.isEnterPressed}
                />
                <ButtonList />
                <ToDoList 
                    todoList={this.state.todoList} 
                    onClick={this.markTodoDone}
                    onMouseDown={this.destroyTodo}
                />
            </div>
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно как то понимать какой элемент из todoList нужно изменить, обычно для этого используют id.

```
this.state = {
      todoList: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Сделать тупую херню', isChecked: false },
        { id: 2, title: 'Сделать тупую херню еще раз', isChecked: false }
      ]
    };

toggleTodoDone(id) {
    const currentTodo = this.state.todoList.find(todo => todo.id === id);
    currentTodo.isChecked = !currentTodo.isChecked;

    this.setState({
      todoList: [...this.state.todoList, currentTodo]
    });
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, что попутно убрали богомерзкое `a === false ? true : false`!)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!